# Akka (java) how to give custom values in application.config like appId and secret keys

Tags: java, configuration, akka

I am working on a akka based project. I bean through the configuration setting page provided in the documentation. I want that I provide all the stuff into application.config file like in my case appId and app secret for twitter accounts.

Is there any way that I provide them in application.config and get them in java files while dealing with my untyped actor.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's very easy, just define them in your config file, then you can retrieve from the actor system from inside your actor:

```
getContext().system().settings().config().getString("appId")
```

You can also create an extension to make loading config values easier, and to encapsulate all config values in one place, an example is given in the official [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/extending-akka.html#Application_specific_settings)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One question that I am using akka 2.2.0 for my project. The link you provided is of snapshot version of akka. Can you guide me any thing related to akka 2.2.0.

Comment: Sure, just browse to http://akka.io/docs/, there are docs for everz major version. For 2.2.0 zou can use the 2.2.4 docs. The specific link to the extension page is http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/java/extending-akka.html#Application_specific_settings